# Tag Manager Trigger with Value of Originating Link Page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

With Google Tag Manager, I want to create a tag that tracks the originating page that links to a form that is in an Iframe, why is a form in an Iframe, because I deal with netsuite, I know, horrible. Anyways, I want to be able to submit the form and pull the url or element by id from the original page where it was linked from. No cross domain as it is all within the same domain. Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well for Form ID and Page url you will need you have predefined variable in GTM
http://take.ms/PPdTj

And for Url of the page on which the iframe exist you would have to modify the href of the iframe and append a parameter with required page url
and then extract the query param using gtm

Comment: Phew, that is definitely a plan, thanks a lot for this, I'll start to attempt it.